# What is the meaning of %F, %T, and %s in fetchmail's mda option?

Tags: procmail, fetchmail

Browsing through web pages around the World Wide Web, I often come across `~/.fetchmailrc` examples such as:

```
poll mail.example.com
    port 993
    proto imap
    user "max123" password "123456"
    mda "/usr/bin/procmail -f %F -d %T"
```

What do the `%F` and `%T` mean? Sometimes, I also see `%s`. Where can I find the documentation of all the available `%` options? I have looked at the [fetchmail manual](https://www.fetchmail.info/fetchmail-man.html), but it doesn't document this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `procmail` option `-f` takes the sender's address as argument, so `%F` most be the "from-address".

The `procmail` option `-d` takes the recipient's address as argument, so `%T` must be the "to-address".

This is also described in the `fetchmail` manual, in the section describing the options `-m` and `--mda`, as well as the configuration keyword `mda`:

> [...] Local delivery addresses will be inserted into the MDA command wherever you place a `%T`; the mail message’s `From` address will be inserted where you place an `%F`. [...]

Regarding `%s`, see the section on `--tracepolls`.  The `%s` is used here as a placeholder for various pieces of information, for presentation  purposes in the manual only:

> Tell `fetchmail` to poll trace information in the form ’`polling account %s`’ and ’`folder %s`’ to the `Received` line it generates, where the `%s` parts are replaced by the user’s remote name, the poll label, and the folder (mailbox) where available (the `Received` header also normally includes the server’s true name). This can be used to facilitate mail filtering based on the account it is being received from. The folder information is written only since version 6.3.4.

So `%s` has nothing to do with the `mda` configuration option.

The `%h` and `%p` are used with `--plugin` (and presumably also with `--plugout`) and will be replaced by a hostname and port number for establishing a TCP connection, e.g. over SSH.  See the manual for the documentation of that option (ask a new question about this option if you are interested in how to use it). These too have nothing to do with the `mda` configuration option.